# how a process know's which child ended?

Tags: c, signals, sigchld

when a process child is terminated he's sending a `SIGCHLD`  to the parent process. Now, if the parent process have more than one child how the parent process knows which child had sent the signal?

Answer (score 2):

The `wait()` syscall returns the `pid` of the child that terminated. You can call `wait()` in your `SIGCHLD` handler to determine which child terminated.

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html):

```
       wait(): on success, returns the process ID of the terminated child;
   on error, -1 is returned.
```

Comment: if i use `wait` it will hold until all the child processes end, but i want it to keep running regardless of other child processes.

Comment: @orenma `wait()` will return when at least one child has terminated, which has happened when your process is sent the `SIGCHLD` signal. Man page: "The wait() system call suspends execution of the calling process until one of its children terminate". However, you can use `waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);` to return immediately if no child is available. Note the `WNOHANG` flag.

Comment: +1 Indeed, calling `waitpid()` in a loop inside the CHLD signal handler itself — both `wait()` and `waitpid()` are [async-signal-safe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04_02) — is a longstanding technique.

Comment: @shanet thanks, that was really helpful.
but what happens when the signal is sent not when the process termineted but when it been suspended or something like that?

Comment: Don't quote me on this because I haven't tried it myself, but when a process is suspended it is sent `SIGSTOP` or `SIGTSTP`. The parent process is only notified when the child terminates. I'm wondering if this is not 100% correct though because I know that bash will show me when a child process is suspended. Maybe @pilcrow can jump in here since he/she seems to have a better handle on signals than I do or you'll have to do some research on your own / open another question.

Comment: @shanet: Whether calls to `wait*()` return for ended children only depends on which options were passed to the call: `UNTRACED` or `WCONTINUED`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `wait()` family of calls as in [@shanet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19813323/132382), the SIGCHLD itself carries that information.

The [`si_pid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/basedefs/signal.h.html) member of the `siginfo_t` member passed to a three-argument signal handler ([SA_SIGINFO](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/sigaction.html)) contains the child's PID.

Comment: Isn't it possible to the handler to be called once for multiple events? If so, this method wouldn't be reliable.

Comment: @ikegami, more precisely put SIGCHLD is not required to queue, so a CHLD generated while one was pending would be lost.  However, the SIGCHLD that _does_ trip the handler _will_ carry the PID of the child that generated it.